# Proof of the derivative of $a^x$

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

I've tried for a while myself from first principles and applying various rules, but always end up going in circles. I've gotten as far as

$$ y = a^x $$
$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = a^x \left( \lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \frac{a^h-1}{h} \right) $$

but I have no idea how I should go about cancelling the $h$ in the denominator. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you know this relation ? $$a^x=\exp(x\ln(a))$$

Comment: Here it's derived: http://www.math.com/tables/derivatives/more/b%5Ex.htm (Using an logarithm/exponential-Identity)

Comment: @NicoDean Interesting, do you have a proof for that identity?

Comment: Actually, you find the answere already at this page: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/587275/finding-the-derivative-of-2x-from-first-terms?rq=1

Comment: @user157789 Some people would take it as the *definition* of $a^x$.

Answer (score 6):

Using the chain rule and assuming you already know that $(\exp)^\prime=\exp,$ you have:

\begin{align}
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}a^x=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}e^{x\ln a}=\ln a\cdot e^{x\ln a}=\ln a\cdot a^x.
\end{align}

Comment: What if $a$ is negative?

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=a^x$. Take the natural logarithm of both sides and rewrite the right-hand side using rules of logarithms to obtain $ln(y)=x\cdot ln(a)$. Differentiate both sides implicitly with respect to $x$. So ${1\over y}y'=ln(a)$. Now multiply both sides of the equation by $y=a^x$ and we have $y'=a^x\cdot ln(a)$.